# How do I build a Cantlin Garden?

Tags: dragon-quest-builders

How do I build a Cantlin Garden in *Dragon Quest Builders* chapter 1 for the challenge? I've tried building inside and outside of town, but to no avail.

I've placed a bench, 10 Flowers, 5 Plants, more than 8 blocks of water, a Plumberry Tree and a Brazier in the room, but the game just says it is a Botanical Garden when I build in the town borders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out. You can't make it outside of town at all.

So what I had to do was tunnel beneath Cantlin to bring water into town. Then you need an open pit room so the tree can grow to full height. From there include all the needed items as outlined in the question. Wait two days for the tree to mature and you will have a Cantlin Garden.

[image: Everything needed for a Cantlin Garden]